# Missing Sharing Settings

Tags: 20.04, settings, desktop-sharing

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; `vino` is installed, updated, rebooted.

In Settings → *Sharing*, the *Screen Sharing* and *File Sharing* settings are missing from the list and I have no idea why. There is only *Media Sharing*. *Screen Sharing* seems to be disabled, despite the missing setting, as I'm unable to run any remote desktop apps.

[image: Clip of Settings GUI]

Comment: Is Samba installed?